# How to run ffmpeg to take x number of screenshots?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to take screenshots of twitch streamers using this code:

```
counter = 0

while counter <=5:
    os.system('ffmpeg -i ' + stream + f' -r 0.5 -f image2 {dir_path}/output_%09d.jpg')
    counter += 1
```

It's my first time working with `ffmpeg` so I thought all I needed was a while loop with a counter to control this but it literally takes thousands of screenshots. Is there a way to stop `ffmpeg` without stopping the entire script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man ffmpeg`

```
    -vframes number (output)
        Set the number of video frames to output. This is an obsolete alias
        for "-frames:v", which you should use instead.
```

An example based on your existing command:

```
ffmpeg -i <stream> -r 0.5 -frames:v 5 -f image2 output_%05d.jpg
```

`-r 0.5` sets the rate, frames per seconds, you will be getting 1 frame every 2 seconds, from the beginning. Alternative you can also set `-ss` to start from a different time.

`-frames:v 5` you will exit after capturing `5` screenshots. You could also use `1` to take one screenshot and exit, if you execute this command into a loop, like in your example. But I think you would prefer to call one `ffmpeg` process for this (without loop).